# inserting into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So my problem is that for some reason, the items do not appear to be going into my database:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

if (isset($_POST['username']) or $_POST['username'] != '') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
mysql_query('Insert into comments VALUES (comment="'.$comment.'", username="'. $username.'")');
echo $username;
}
else {
    mysql_query('insert into comments values (comment="'.$comment.'")');
}
```

My table is named comments, one field is named comment, and one field is named username.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: For the record, that code has a very high potential for SQL injection. **Always** filter your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL insert format is incorrect :-

```
insert into comments
(list of columns...)  values ( list of values ...);
```

Or

```
insert into comments
set column1=value1, column2=value2 ...;
```

If you do a `var_dump(mysql_error());`,
you should able to see more verbose details on the error

Off-topic :-

You insert statement does not cater for sql injection,
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: I know, was going to add that later.

Answer (score 0):

First come to mind:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) or $_POST['username'] != '') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];//If you use OR in the condition. $username could be not set of maybe ''
```

So replace OR with AND, so when you get inside the true condition of the If, $username will have something

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code is given below......
I have used this technique in my previous php projects....
May be usefull to you..

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

if (isset($_POST['username']) AND $_POST['username'] != '') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
mysql_query("Insert into comments VALUES ('".$comment."', '".$username."')");
echo $username;
}
else {
    mysql_query("insert into comments values ('".$comment."')");
}
```